# Parsing xml from website

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

i have an xml file located at

http://androtrends.hostingsiteforfree.com/direct.xml

i am trying to parse this xml file to use it in my program but every time the program force closes although it has no errors.i am new to java, please help!

Following is the code which i have used in XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser {


public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
//Parsing XML content and getting DOM element
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
            // return DOM
        return doc;
}

//Getting each xml child element value by passing element node name


public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = ((Document) item).getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
} 
public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
  } 

}
```

The code for **Channel.java** is

```
public class Channel extends ListActivity{

String selectedmode, channelName, channelLink;

Intent urlIntent;
    // All static variables

static final String DirectURL = "http://androtrends.hostingsiteforfree.com/direct.xml";

static final String FlashURL="http://androtrends.hostingsiteforfree.com/direct.xml";

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_Channel = "channel";
static final String KEY_Link = "link";
String xml;
Toast toast;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.channels);
    selectedmode=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    urlIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wait 60 secs to load the stream...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    updatechannels();

    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            channelName= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.channelName)).getText().toString();
            channelLink= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.channelLink)).getText().toString();
            urlIntent.setData(Uri.parse(channelLink));
            toast.show();
            startActivity(urlIntent);
        }
    });
}

    private void updatechannels() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    if (selectedmode.equalsIgnoreCase("direct"))
    {
         xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(DirectURL); // getting XML
    }else
    {
         xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(FlashURL);
    }
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_Channel, parser.getValue(e, KEY_Channel));
        map.put(KEY_Link, parser.getValue(e, KEY_Link));


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  KEY_Channel, KEY_Link }, new int[] {
                    R.id.channelName, R.id.channelLink });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: This is such a common misunderstanding.  If you program has no errors, it will not crash.  You only have no compile time errors since you cannot get runtime errors until you fix the compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NetActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://androtrends.hostingsiteforfree.com/direct.xml";


    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;  

    ItemAdapter adapter1;

    ListView list;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_net);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();          

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
             new XmlParsing(url).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});
         else
             new XmlParsing(url).execute(new String[]{null});   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class XmlParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // variables passed in:
        String urls;
        //  constructor
        public XmlParsing(String urls) {
            this.urls = urls;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NetActivity.this, "Fetching Details..", "Please wait...", true);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            URL url;
            try {

                url = new URL(urls);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("channel");
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                    title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("channel : "+((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                    Element fstElmnt1 = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList1 = fstElmnt1.getElementsByTagName("link");
                    Element nameElement1 = (Element) nameList1.item(0);
                    nameList1 = nameElement1.getChildNodes();
                    description.add(""+ ((Node) nameList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("link : "+ ((Node) nameList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());           


                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Now we have your JSONObject, play around with it.
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            String value = result;

           // Log.v("URL  Res- - - -", ""+value);

            adapter1 = new ItemAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter1);

        }

    }


class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title_text;
            public TextView des_text;
        }

        public ItemAdapter(XmlParsing xmlParsing) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
        }

        //@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return title.size();
        }

        //@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainpage_listitem_activity, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                holder.des_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des_text);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.title_text.setText(""+title.get(position));      

            holder.des_text.setText(""+description.get(position));

        return view;
        }
    }
}
```